# Displaying nested JSON data Angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, typescript

I am using a third party API which provides a nested JSON object in return. I'm converting this data into CSV. I have used http get request to get data. The data looks good in console but does not bind with HTML. When I download the CSV file, I only see objects. I should be able to see the value of those objects in the downloaded file instead. The CSV file is automatically downloaded when I navigate to that menu. I want it to download only on "Export CSV" button click. Can someone help me with it? Thanks.

```
Array(10)
0: {_id: "611368f375aeaa23cce260fa", customer: {…}, transaction: {…}, serviceProvider: {…}, couponSurvey: {…}, …}
1: {_id: "6113685775aeaa23cce260f4", customer: {…}, transaction: {…}, serviceProvider: {…}, couponSurvey: {…}, …}
2: {_id: "611269c43d37b7199c620db7", customer: {…}, transaction: {…}, serviceProvider: {…}, couponSurvey: {…}, …}
3: {_id: "611269843d37b7199c620db2", customer: {…}, transaction: {…}, serviceProvider: {…}, couponSurvey: {…}, …}
4: {_id: "611268f63d37b7199c620dad", customer: {…}, transaction: {…}, serviceProvider: {…}, couponSurvey: {…}, …}
5: {_id: "611268c73d37b7199c620da8", customer: {…}, transaction: {…}, serviceProvider: {…}, couponSurvey: {…}, …}
6: {_id: "61125dc428ed930c0e05c3b1", customer: {…}, transaction: {…}, serviceProvider: {…}, couponSurvey: {…}, …}
7: {_id: "6112565c28ed930c0e05c3ac", customer: {…}, transaction: {…}, serviceProvider: {…}, couponSurvey: {…}, …}
8: {_id: "611254b75dcb9a5af3b3b1a5", customer: {…}, transaction: {…}, serviceProvider: {…}, couponSurvey: {…}, …}
9: {_id: "611254605dcb9a5af3b3b1a2", customer: {…}, transaction: {…}, serviceProvider: {…}, couponSurvey: {…}, …}
```

Data looks like this in the console.

.ts file

```
  loading = false;
  showTransactionValue = false;
  var: any;
  bucket: any[] = [];

this.api.fetchTableData('transfer/get-transactions', params, true).then((data) => {
      this.transID = '';
      this.loading = false;
      
      this.var = data.docs;
      this.page.rows = data.docs;
      this.page.count = data.total;
  
      this.results(data);  
      console.log(data.docs);
      
      Object.entries(this.var.matches).map( res => {
        this.bucket.push(this.var[1])
      });
     
      
    },
```

.html file

```
<div class="form-group">
<button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect btn-sm text-white" (click)="results()">Export CSV</button>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let item of bucket;">{{item?._id}}</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?>

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: You’ll get much better responses if you provide a clear example of what you are expecting and a clear example of what your are getting. Or even better a stackblitz.